# Tangency of tangent function please help

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of tangent function?
The question is find the equation of the tangent line to:
$$y=\tan(x) \text{ at } x=\frac{\pi}4 \text{ or }-45^\circ$$ 
Please help!

Comment: The derivative of the tangent function is $\sec^2x$. (Hint on how to prove this: $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$. Use the quotient rule.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the general equation of a tangent line to some function $f$ at point $(a, f(a))$:

$y = f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$

$f(x)=\tan(x) \Longrightarrow f'(x) = \sec^2(x) \Longrightarrow f'(-\frac{\pi}{4}) = 2$

Thus, the tangent line to $y = \tan(x)$ at $(-\frac{\pi}{4}, -1)$ is:

$$
y = 2\left(x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)-1 \quad \text{or} \quad y = 2x + \frac{\pi}{2} -1
$$